# how to check if input type number is empty in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to check if the number input element is empty using jquery

```
<input type="number" name="year" id="year" min="1900" max="2017">
```

Comment: `if ( $('#year').val() === "" ) {..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
if($("#year").val() == "" || $("#year").val() == null){
    //code goes here
}
```

You just have to target the element by ID, get its value and check if its an empty string or null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just `if (!$("#year").val()) {` will do.